# Why did I have to correct the spring roo code?

Tags: spring-roo

I created a very simple working project using Spring Roo 2 M3 with Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3.  It simply lists the contents of a MySQL table and allows me to edit it.  I could not get the show unless I pushed in the following code and manually corrected it:

```
package org.oclc.web;
import org.oclc.domain.SFDCRecordTypeAccount;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller.annotations.ControllerType;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller.annotations.RooController;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.thymeleaf.annotations.RooThymeleaf;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * = SFDCRecordTypeAccountsItemThymeleafController
 *
 * TODO Auto-generated class documentation
 *
 */
@RooController(entity = SFDCRecordTypeAccount.class, type = ControllerType.ITEM)
@RooThymeleaf
public class SFDCRecordTypeAccountsItemThymeleafController {

/**
 * TODO Auto-generated method documentation
 * 
 * @param sFDCRecordTypeAccount
 * @param model
 * @return ModelAndView
 */
@GetMapping(name = "show")
public ModelAndView show(@ModelAttribute SFDCRecordTypeAccount sFDCRecordTypeAccount, Model model) {
    ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("sfdcrecordtypeaccounts/show");
    model1.addObject("sFDCRecordTypeAccount",sFDCRecordTypeAccount);
    return (model1);
}
```

}

Did I do something wrong when I generated the original code?  Below are the contents of my log.roo file:

```
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-03-02 16:39:23
project setup --topLevelPackage org.oclc --projectName "eadIntegration11" --java 8 --packaging JAR
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-03-02 16:39:24
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log opened at 2017-03-02 16:39:27
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL
entity jpa --class ~.domain.SFDCRecordTypeAccount --table sfdc_record_type_account --identifierColumn sfdc_record_type_account_id --identifierStrategy AUTO --sequenceName sequenceName --identifierType java.lang.Integer
field string --fieldName sfdcRecordTypeId --column sfdc_record_type_id
field string --fieldName siebelRecordTypeId --column siebel_record_type_id
// [failed] field string --fieldName sfdcRecordTypeId
repository jpa --all
finder add --entity ~.domain.SFDCRecordTypeAccount --name findById
service --all
web mvc setup
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc templates setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --entity ~.domain.SFDCRecordTypeAccount --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc finder --all --responseType THYMELEAF
exit
// Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 [rev 20a0f71] log closed at 2017-03-02 17:05:22
```

Here is the error in the log:

```
2017-03-02 17:01:30.501 ERROR 11956 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "sfdcrecordtypeaccounts/show": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/sfdcrecordtypeaccounts/show.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/sfdcrecordtypeaccounts/show.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:667) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1087) [thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1061) [thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:53) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "sfdcRecordTypeId" (template: "sfdcrecordtypeaccounts/show" - line 168, col 27)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "sfdcRecordTypeId" (template: "sfdcrecordtypeaccounts/show" - line 168, col 27)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SelectionVariableExpression.executeSelectionVariableExpression(SelectionVariableExpression.java:157) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:90) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:125) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:82) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1304) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1567) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1620) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1567) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1620) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'sfdcRecordTypeId' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Integer' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330) ~[spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:277) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you provide more info about the problem that appears using the default generated code?

Comment: I'm not able to provide you an answer without the error trace that appears you using the default generated code... please, provide it to try to find a solution.

Comment: Added new log.roo file and stack trace from default generated code.

Comment: Thanks! We're going to check it ASAP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, thanks for your contribution to the Spring Roo project!

We've just detected that the Spring Roo project was not generating correct code with entities that starts with more than one uppercase letter.

We've just updated the generated code to prevent this type of errors.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/commit/23959de37f38abf4f210f3cfb6faca5a061b4e15

This fix will be available in the Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 version that will be published this week.

Regards,